# Changing rows with certain column values

Tags: r, dataframe, r-package

I have a data frame with 3 columns $a (char), $b (char), and $c (int).

```
   a       b     c
1  NA      NA    NA
2  NA    Donald  0
3  shawn  john   120
.
.
.
```

I would like to replace the rows where df$c==0 and df$a==NA but keep df$b as is.
I want something like `df[df$a &&  df$c==0  ==NA] <- c("IGNORED",same as before,"IGNORED")`

So my second row will become

```
2  IGNORED  Donald  IGNORED
```

I have to use column names, and not column numbers. Is there a package you recommend? Or the base functions would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get all the rows where your condition holds:

```
replaces <- which(is.na(df$a) & df$c == 0)
```

Then update the 'a' and 'c' fields, leaving 'b' unchanged:

```
df[replaces,]$a <- 'IGNORED'
df[replaces,]$c <- 'IGNORED'
```